# Interval 30 days getting converted to Interval 4 weeks 2 days

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-bigquery, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

I am getting an error in a PySpark code when I am using below query in spark.sql clause, and it is supporting in BigQuery when I run it in BigQuery directly.

```
df = spark.sql('''SELECT h.src, AVG(h.norm_los) AS 

mbr_avg FROM UM h WHERE h.orig_dt < 

date_sub(current_date,INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CAST((DATE_ADD(DATE(h.orig_dt), INTERVAL 18 

MONTH)) AS DATE) >= date_sub(current_date,INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND h.src IS NOT NULL GROUP BY 

h.src_cumb_id''')
```

When I am running the same query using PySpark under dataproc cluster, it is converting the  `interval 30 days`  to  `interval 4 weeks 2 days`
and I am getting below error.

> cannot resolve 'date_sub(current_date(), interval 4 weeks 2 days)' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires int type, however, 'interval 4 weeks 2 days' is of calendarinterval type

Note: I am using option("intermediateFormat","orc") as well.

Any help on this would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little bit changes to the above query and now its working as expected.

**Updated Query:**

```
spark.sql(SELECT h.src, AVG(h.norm_los) AS 
mbr_avg FROM UM h WHERE h.orig_dt < 
date_sub(current_date,30) AND CAST((add_months(DATE(h.orig_dt),-18)) AS DATE) >= date_sub(current_date,30) AND h.src IS NOT NULL GROUP BY
h.src_cumb_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

`date_sub` in Spark SQL [1](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.8/api/sql/index.html#date_sub) and BigQuery [2](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_sub) are different.

In Spark SQL

> date_sub(start_date, num_days) - Returns the date that is num_days before start_date.

Examples:

```
> SELECT date_sub('2016-07-30', 1);
 2016-07-29
```

Comment: Thank You for clearing it out. Could you please make me understand, how can I convert it in such a way, that it works in both platform? Should I pass my QUERY in a different way, or i will have to create a new query all together?

Comment: AFAIK, Spark SQL and BigQuery use different SQL dialects and have their own built-in functions, they are similar but not exactly the same. I think you have to convert them manually.